# From uploaded zipped shapefile to Geopandas DataFrame in Django Application

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, error, django

I'm trying to get to a point where I can quickly filter thousands of points in a shapefile. My Django application asks for a zipped shapefile to upload, where the zipped file contains at least the `.shp`, `.shx`, and `.dbf` files. Once in my Django view, the zip file is as follows:

`request.FILES['file']` > `<InMemoryUploadedFile: test.zip (application/x-zip-compressed)>`

`type(request.FILES['file'])` > `<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>`

`request.FILES['file'].file` > `<_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000028E29F8FE00>`

Assuming Geopandas is the best option for efficient filtering/masking (if I'm wrong, I'm definitely open to suggestions), I'm not sure how to go from current state to a Geopandas DataFrame. When I try to use the `read_file()` method

```py
import geopandas as gpd
gpd.read_file(request.FILES['file'].file)
```

I get the following error:

> `fiona.errors.DriverError: no driver`

The `geopandas.read_file()` [docs](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.read_file.html#geopandas.read_file) state:

> Either the absolute or relative path to the file or URL to be opened,
> or any object with a `read()` method (such as an open file or StringIO)

I'm not sure how to get what I have into an appropriate format for the `read_file()` method.

*Note:* The masking and filtering I'm looking to perform are on attribute data and not the geometry.

Comment: I think you can also use this syntax: `zipfile = "zip:///Users/name/Downloads/cb_2017_us_state_500k.zip"
states = geopandas.read_file(zipfile)` from the official docs - https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `fiona.io.ZipMemoryFile` and `gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features`.

Example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import io
from fiona.io import ZipMemoryFile

# Just to create a BytesIO object for the demo,
# similar to your request.FILES['file'].file
zipshp = io.BytesIO(open('test.zip', 'rb').read())

with (ZipMemoryFile(zipshp)) as memfile:
    with memfile.open() as src:
        crs = src.crs
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(src, crs=crs)
        print(gdf.head())
```

Note, I originally didn't include the `BytesCollection` as the fiona developer stated in a comment on [my previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/225589/2856) that the class would likely be deprecated.  However, if you use it, you shouldn't need `ZipMemoryFile`. This works for me:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import io
import fiona


zipshp = io.BytesIO(open('test.zip', 'rb').read())

with fiona.BytesCollection(zipshp.read()) as src:
    crs = src.crs
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(src, crs=crs)
    print(gdf.head())
```

Answer (score 3):

@user2856's answer got me half way to a solution. I would not have known about `fiona.io.ZipMemoryFile`, and that led me to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/225589/34900). Combining the two solutions gave me:

```py
with ZipMemoryFile(request.FILES['file'].file) as memfile:
    with fiona.BytesCollection(memfile._initial_bytes) as f:
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(f, crs='epsg:4326')
        print(gdf.head())
```

I now have my shapefile data in a GeoDataFrame.

For anyone who's curious, the reason I went with `BytesCollection` instead of `memfile.open()` is because I couldn't get `memfile.open()` to work. It would throw an error saying the `.open()` method was missing a 'path' positional argument.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://geopandas.org/en/v0.13.2/docs/user_guide/io.html), you only need geopandas and [fiona](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/) library installed:

> You can also load ZIP files that contain your data:
>
> zipfile = "filename.zip"
> states = geopandas.read_file(zipfile)

Note: [fiona](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/) library is mentioned in previous gpd docs, and in this one for other features. not sure it is strictly needed for zip files, but it's a useful library for spatial manipulations