# Encoding issue while making GeoDataFrame from shapefile using URL

Tags: geopandas, encoding, url, geodataframe

The dataset I want to use have some special characters like **ü, õ, ö, ä**. which cause encoding issue.

The below example runs totally fine and doesnt mess up those characters.

```py
gdf_local = gpd.read_file(r'my-local-machine-path\maakond_shp.zip', encoding = 'iso-8859-15')
```

However the problem is that I want to create multiple geo data frames, plus have to share script only, so its not feasible to download all of those shapefiles to my machine first and hence I want to create geodataframes directly from the URL. one of the example below works but messes up the special characters.

```py
url = 'https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/docs/haldus_asustus/maakond_shp.zip?t=20220501011007'
gdf_url = gpd.read_file(url) # it works but messes up those special characters
```

Next I tried the following

```
gdf_url = gpd.read_file(url , encoding = 'iso-8859-15') # it gives error
```

But it threw this error: **TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for keyword argument 'encoding'**

Apparently geopandas try utf-8 by default which is causing issue in my case but doesn't let me use different encoding.

Is there any workaround or solution for this?

**Broken attempts:**

```
gdf['mycol'] = gdf.mycol.str.encode('iso-8859-15') # messed it way more. tried using different encodings etc but no help
```

tried requests method to make file first then gdf but didnt worked.

finally tried the following solution [Reading raw data into geopandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225586/reading-raw-data-into-geopandas) but it also messed up those characters.

```py
url = 'https://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/docs/haldus_asustus/maakond_shp.zip?t=20220501011007'
request = requests.get(url)
b = bytes(request.content)

with fiona.BytesCollection(b) as f:
    crs = f.crs
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(f, crs=crs)
    print(gdf.head())
```

Comment: try the [Windows-1257](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1257) i.e. `encoding = 'cp1252'`

Comment: issue is not using wrong encoder. even 'iso-8859-15' is also working .
Main prob is that whilst trying to make df using URL when i try to add encoding attribute it throws the error which is strange. as it shud not throw error and it doesnt throw error when i try making df from local path.
any idea why its behaving this way? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in a dependency of geopandas, the `fiona` package.
It was discussed on github [here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/1048) and should be fixed on a newer release (>=1.8.21).

So try updating the `fiona` package and see if it works.

Comment: it worked with the following.
gpd ver: 0.10.2
fiona ver: 1.8.21